# Heap corruption when using make_shared

Tags: c++

I have a class with private member variable

```
shared_ptr<short> m_p_data;
```

I get heap corruption when I use this constructor:

```
Volume2D(const int dimX, const int dimY) :m_dimX{ dimX }, m_dimY{ dimY }, m_p_data{ make_shared<short>(dimX*dimY) } {
}
```

but there is no heap corruption if I do this instead:

```
Volume2D(const int dimX, const int dimY) :m_dimX(dimX), m_dimY(dimY) {
  m_p_data.reset(new short[dimX*dimY]);
}
```

To be more specific, here is the code that corrupts the heap:

```
Volume2D vol(10, 1);
for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    vol(i, 0) = i;
    cout << "value = " << vol(i, 0) << endl;
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Both versions of your code are problematic.

The first version,

```
make_shared<short>(dimX*dimY)
```

creates a *single* heap-allocated short with the value `dimX*dimY`. It is apparent from the rest of your question, that your code later treats this logically as an *array* of dimension `dimX*dimY`, which is exactly what's causing the heap corruption (you only allocated a single `short`, but you're treating it like many).

The second version has the opposite problem. You're allocating `dimX*dimY` shorts, but, as far as your `shared_ptr`, it doesn't know that. So it doesn't have your heap corruption, but the `shared_ptr` destructor calls `delete`, not `delete[]` (even though you allocated with `new[]`, not `new`).

---

For this case, its' unclear why you need a `shared_ptr` to begin with. Why not use `std::vector<short>`, or `std::vector<std::vector<short>>`?